# How to convert 1d array to 3d array (convert grayscale image so rgb format )?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have an image in the numpy array format, I wrote the code assuming rgb image as input but I have found that the input consists of black and white image.

for what should have been a RGB i.e (256,256,3) dimension image, I got the input as Grayscale (256,256) array image and I want to convert it to (256,256,3)

This is what I have in numpy array:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
(256, 256)
```

This is what I want:(an array of same elements 3 times for every value in the array above)

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Is there any numpy function that does this?
If not is there any way to do this in python array and convert it to numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. You can use opencv for this. To converts the image from Gray to RGB:

> ```
> import cv2
> import numpy as np
> gray = np.random.rand(256, 256)
> gary2rgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
> ```

2. Using only numpy, you can do it in the following way:

> ```
> import numpy as np
> def convert_gray2rgb(image):
>     width, height = image.shape
>     out = np.empty((width, height, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
>     out[:, :, 0] = image
>     out[:, :, 1] = image
>     out[:, :, 2] = image
>     return out
>
> gray = np.random.rand(256, 256)  # gray scale image
> gray2rgb = convert_gray2rgb(gray)
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`numpy.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack the 2D arrays along the third axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.dstack([a, a, a])
```

results:

```
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]
 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]]
```

or use opencv [`merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) function to merge 3 color channels.